# Iterate different objects as String with RedisTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have different models keys in redis.

I used these templates to store the values;

```
public RedisTemplate<String, Model1> model1RedisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Model1> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Model1.class));
        return redisTemplate;
    }

public RedisTemplate<String, Model2> model2RedisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Model2> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Model2.class));
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

This is how I stored the values :

```
model1RedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(model1.getId(), model1);
model2RedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(model2.getId(), model2);
```

Now I want to iterate all raw values as String using one redis template like `RedisTemplate<String,String> redisTemplateForAllValues;`

How can I do that?

Comment: not understand what you want can you please describe more

Comment: I want iterate all data in redis using one redis template like : `RedisTemplate<String,String> templateForAllValues`

Answer (score 1):

there is no native method to get all values from Redis with redisTemplate

but you can get with the following method:

```
public List<String> getAllValues(){
   Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.keys("*");// you can use any specific pattern of key
   return redisTemplate.opsForValue().multiGet(keys);
}
```